# nested elements to attributes

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

My input xml is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <foobar>
    <foo>
        <a>
            <a>
                <a>atr1</a>
                <v>NO</v>
            </a>
            <a>
                <a>more</a>
                <v>more</v>
            </a>
        </a>
        <v>ONE</v>
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <baz>
            <a>
                <a>
                    <a>attr</a>
                    <v>123</v>
                </a>
                <a>
                    <a>attr222</a>
                    <v>22</v>
                </a>
            </a>
            <v>TWO</v>
        </baz>
        <a>
            <a>
                <a>atr6</a>
                <v>ATR</v>
                </a>
           </a>
 </bar>
  <a>
   <a>
      <a>atr0</a>
      <v>NO</v>
  </a>
  <a>
      <a>atr2</a>
      <v>NO</v>
</a>
</a>
</foobar>
```

My desired output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foobar atr0="NO" atr2="NO">
    <foo atr1="NO" more="more">ONE</foo>
    <bar atr6="ATR">
        <baz attr="123" attr222="22">TWO</baz>
    </bar>
</foobar>
```

i am trying to convert all the nested elements into attributes. 
My xslt script is-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Matches all of nodes -->
<xsl:template match = "node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:for-each select= "*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{//a[text()]}">
    <xsl:value-of select="//v[text()]"/>
  </xsl:attribute>  
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the script is converting the first foobar element to attribute only. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `xsl:apply-templates` so you never get past that first root element. Also, `node()` includes text, comments, and processing instructions and you don't want to try to create an attribute if you match one of those.

Try something like this instead...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[a]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|a/a"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::a)]"/>                
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a/a" priority="1">
        <xsl:attribute name="{a}">
            <xsl:value-of select="v"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<foobar atr0="NO" atr2="NO">
   <foo atr1="NO" more="more">ONE</foo>
   <bar atr6="ATR">
      <baz attr="123" attr222="22">TWO</baz>
   </bar>
</foobar>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code is doing:

You are selecting **one** `node()`: `foobar`, when you are inside it you have a `for-each` and there you select **any** node in current context: `*`, so you match `foo`, and from there you get all the `//a` that contain text (the only one: `atr1`) and all the `//v` that contain text: `NO`. And since you never call `<xsl:apply-templates>` or use some expression to process the nodes down the tree, no other templates are ever called.

You need to process other nodes recursively. Also, you can't just use `//a` because in some nodes there are more than one `a` and you would end up with all of them concatenated.

One way to do it is using multiple recursive templates. This is a possible solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::a)][not(self::v)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="a">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="a" />   
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::a)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[following-sibling::v][text()]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{normalize-space(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::v" />
        </xsl:attribute>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a" /> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```