# Combine xslt grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping, nested-attributes

my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<struct name="foolist"> 
<!-- this is a comment -->  
<foo age="12" dob="2012">foo</foo>
<foo age="20" dob="1999">foo</foo>
<bar age="24">bar</bar>
</struct>
```

Desired output using xslt 1.0 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<struct> 
   <c>     this is a comment    </c> 
   <s>   
      <s>      
         <foo> 
            <a> 
               <a>    
                  <a>age</a>    
                  <v>12</v>  
               </a> 
               <a>    
                  <a>dob</a>    
                  <v>2012</v>  
               </a>
            </a> 
            <v>foo</v>     
         </foo>     
         <foo> 
            <a>
               <a>    
                  <a>age</a>    
                  <v>20</v>  
               </a> 
               <a>    
                  <a>dob</a>    
                  <v>1999</v>  
               </a> 
            </a> 
            <v>foo</v>      
         </foo>  
      </s>   
      <s>    
         <bar> 
            <a>
               <a>    
                  <a>age</a>    
                  <v>20</v>  
               </a>
            </a> 
            <v>bar</v>      
         </bar>    
      </s> 
   </s> 
   <a>  
      <a>      
         <a>name</a>      
         <v>foolist</v>    
      </a> 
   </a> 
</struct>
```

my xslt is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="adjacentByName" match="*/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1])" />

<xsl:template match="comment()|*">

        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="comment()|*"/>
      <s>
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('adjacentByName', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))[1])]">
    <s>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('adjacentByName', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </s>
</xsl:for-each>
 </s>  
          <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        </a>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />

    </xsl:copy> 

</xsl:template>



<!-- Matches all attributes -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <a>
        <a><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></a>
        <v><xsl:value-of select="." /></v>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Matches text nodes -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <v><xsl:value-of select="." /></v>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <c><xsl:value-of select="." /></c>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am only having problem with the "s" tags otherwise everything else is working fine. i am trying to put all the same elements in separate "s" tag and all the child elements of root element in one "s" tag.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is your expected output such an overly complicated structure? How could that possibly be of use?

Comment: this is the process of expanding the structure of the XML data in order to meet the requirements of the Packedobjects compressor. By increasing the size of the markup language and adding redundant data the XML document is transformed into structured data with compact and concise elements which benefits of a unique (highly unlikely to be adopted) pattern. @MathiasMüller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I find kind of disturbing is that in a [previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154852/nested-elements-to-attributes) you asked the *exact same thing*, just in the opposite direction. Why is that?

It is not entirely clear what the rules and constraints are , but I'll give it a try.

I have rewritten the stylesheet and it seems to me that it is much easier to understand now. You still have to reintroduce grouping with keys, but I understood that is not a difficulty for you.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:key name="adjacent" match="*/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1])" />

   <xsl:template match="/struct">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="comment()"/>
           <s>  
               <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('adjacent', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))[1])]">
                   <s>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('adjacent', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))"/>
                   </s>
               </xsl:for-each>
           </s>
           <a>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
           </a>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="comment()">
       <c>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </c>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="foo|bar">
        <xsl:copy>
            <a>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            </a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*">
       <a>
           <a>
               <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
           </a>
           <v>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </v>
       </a>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()">
       <v>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </v>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<struct>
   <c> this is a comment </c>
   <s>
      <s>
         <foo>
            <a>
               <a>
                  <a>age</a>
                  <v>12</v>
               </a>
               <a>
                  <a>dob</a>
                  <v>2012</v>
               </a>
            </a>
            <v>foo</v>
         </foo>
         <foo>
            <a>
               <a>
                  <a>age</a>
                  <v>20</v>
               </a>
               <a>
                  <a>dob</a>
                  <v>1999</v>
               </a>
            </a>
            <v>foo</v>
         </foo>
      </s>
      <s>
         <bar>
            <a>
               <a>
                  <a>age</a>
                  <v>24</v>
               </a>
            </a>
            <v>bar</v>
         </bar>
      </s>
   </s>
   <a>
      <a>
         <a>name</a>
         <v>foolist</v>
      </a>
   </a>
</struct>
```

Comment: the previous question was for decompression...this one is for compression....thnx

Comment: @Sam If you are responsible for the input XML in the first place, why would you have to write another transformation to reverse the process instead of simply sticking with the original format?

Comment: 1 xslt file is to get original xml file converted into highly structured file so that libpackedobject( a compressing tool) compresses the file and send it over a network. on the receiving end the file need to be decompressed into its orginal format using the other xslt file.

Comment: @Sam I see - now it actually makes sense to me. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: the foolist attribute in struct element is not available in the output...i can get that sorted..only thing i need is to use the grouping code combine with the existing code...thanx a lot for your time @Mathias....

Comment: @Sam I have adjusted the code to include the missing attribute.

Comment: @Sam Another update, now my stylesheet includes adjacent grouping and produces eactly the wanted output.

Comment: thnx a lot.that was very helpful @mathias...i was confused where to use the grouping codes..

Comment: @mathias..i have another problem now....just to test i added a child element (bar2) to bar element. but in output bar2 is sequenced with the foo elements..why is that?..thnks in advance..u can c it here..[http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/r6qkno/2